# Laravel 5.2 reCaptcha fails after succeeds

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, recaptcha

So, I have placed the reCaptcha in my login form. I click on "im not a robot" and click on the right images and it says it succeeded, but when I submit the form it returns me the message of "The Captcha field is not correct." and it also thrown and exception saying:

> 'Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidationException' with message
>   'The given data failed to pass validation.'

I am using "greggilbert/recaptcha" in my Laravel 5.2 project. I have set my keys and everything is working great in production and in other localhost's but not in mine.

My team and I work in the same git repository and it works for everyone but not for me.
I have re-installed the plugin, also the whole composer (by deleting vendor and then `composer install`).

I have cleared the configuration with `php artisan config:clear` and I've done the `composer dump-autoload` and have re-publish the ServiceProvider with `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Greggilbert\Recaptcha\RecaptchaServiceProvider"`

Does somebody have any idea on how to fix this? Please!

Thank you a lot for reading this! Happy coding!

Comment: Press F12 and tell if there are any blocked requests by some plugins (update your webbrowser, try to do this in incognito mode, etc.)

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek console doesn't show anything because it validates right in the front end, it fails in the backend and redirects with the error. Incognito mode not helping either.

Comment: Maybe different browser will help you? Also clean the `storage/framework/sessions` directory. Does your verification route requires CSRF token?

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek I've tried with all browsers and all private mode available. I even reinstalled the project and of course cleaned the storage, but no :( another idea?

Comment: Increase logging level to catch every bit of information that flows between your view and controller, you can install postman extension (Google Chrome) to see more data about requests. It could be also worth to check if this is not fault of your PC - try to find some websites that are using recaptcha2 and check if you pass the validation. Maybe you are working behind proxy or something else, it's hard to say.